# Error while deploying my app on heroku - tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, heroku

I want to deploy my flask app on heroku which contains an application using tensorflow, but I received this error:

```
remote:        Collecting tensorboard==2.0.2 (from -r /tmp/build_e8c9bbdcb75f1c632603c5c3412543f6/requirements.txt (line 53))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/54/99b9d5d52d5cb732f099baaaf7740403e83fe6b0cedde940fabd2b13d75a/tensorboard-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (3.8MB)
remote:        Collecting tensorflow==2.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_e8c9bbdcb75f1c632603c5c3412543f6/requirements.txt (line 54))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_e8c9bbdcb75f1c632603c5c3412543f6/requirements.txt (line 54)) (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
remote:        No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_e8c9bbdcb75f1c632603c5c3412543f6/requirements.txt (line 54))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to i-sip111.
```

Can you please guide me how to solve this problem. My python version in virtual env is 3.7.3,  and I received the error while pushing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Tensorflow Install guide (https://www.tensorflow.org/install), it requires pip version >19.0. Did you run:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

before installing tensorflow?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I've already done this. I also did it again and as you can see I received this msg: 
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (19.3.1)

Comment: can you describe how you are installing tensorflow ?

Comment: I installed it by using:   
pip install --upgrade tensorflow

Comment: I used the information in this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue. In the error response, it lists all of the versions currently available as a result of the version of pip they have on Heroku.

Use the following command in your virtual environment to downgrade your version of TensorFlow to the latest one they support:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0b1
```

Then update your requirements.txt file using the following command

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Finally, push your app to Heroku again and you should be all set. :)

```
git push heroku master
```

[Reference issue on Tensorflow Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34840)